# Google Hangout Button: How to name the conversation?

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I have integrated the google hangout button in my project by using following code

Source: [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button)

Hangout button demo: Inviting people

**Problem**

The hangout is named as `Unnamed Hangout` as shown in screenshot below:

[image]

Is it possible to give a name to the hangout call?

Answer (score 0):

I've created this way:

```
<div id="placeholder">&nbsp;</div>
<script>
  gapi.hangout.render('placeholder', {
    'topic': 'TITLE',
    'render': 'createhangout',
    'hangout_type': 'onair',
    'invites': [{ 'id': 'example@email.com', 'invite_type' : 'EMAIL' }, ],
    'widget_size': 175,
    'initial_apps': [{
      'app_id' : '937231998771',
      'app_type' : 'ROOM_APP' 
    }]
  });
  window.___gcfg = {
    lang: 'es-419'
  };
</script>
```